# How to Correcly Filter Through Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am trying to compare two arrays but it is not filtering correctly. I am trying to add users, my function compares the ID and StaffID and if the StaffID is not in the current user array it should set the state of new user so they can be added.

```
export default function AddUserDropdown({onChange}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersToAdd();
  }, []);

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    open: false,
    name: '',
    users: [],
    id: null,
  });

  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    newUsers: []
  })

  const getUsersToAdd = () => {
    axios.all([
      axios.get('/updateUserList'),
      axios.get('/userInformation')
    ])
      .then(axios.spread((newUserBox, currentUserBox) => {
        let newUserIds = [];
        let currentUserIds = [];

        for (let newUser of currentUserBox.data){
          newUserIds.push(newUser.id);
        }

        for (let user of newUserBox.data) {
          if (!newUserIds[user.staffID]) {
            currentUserIds.push(user);
          }
        }

        setUser({...user, newUsers: currentUserIds });
      }));
    }

    // ...
  };

  // ...
};
```

When the axios calls request userinformation endpoint it returns this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Elton",
    "lastName": "Frederick",
    "departmentId": 1,
    "admin": true,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Developer",
    "vh5given": 31,
    "vh5rec": 280,
    "profilePic": "https://www.travelplannersinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Elton.jpg",
    "password": "abc234"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Julio",
    "lastName": "Probando",
    "departmentId": 1,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": true,
    "position": "Lead Dev",
    "vh5given": 11,
    "vh5rec": 339,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Julio_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc232"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Corey",
    "lastName": "Chris",
    "departmentId": 2,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Customer Service",
    "vh5given": 14,
    "vh5rec": 167,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Corey.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "Daisy",
    "lastName": "Ramos",
    "departmentId": 3,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "ATC",
    "vh5given": 22,
    "vh5rec": 202,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Daisy_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc321"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "firstName": "Air Car Hotel",
    "lastName": "Nunca",
    "departmentId": 4,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 25,
    "profilePic": "profile.jpg",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "firstName": "Jenn",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "departmentId": 4,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Vp Of Sales",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 0,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Jenn2_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "firstName": "Reyna",
    "lastName": "Pagan",
    "departmentId": 5,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Agent Support Manager",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 20,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Reyna_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "firstName": "Ameilia",
    "lastName": "Rodriguez",
    "departmentId": 6,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Human Resources",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 5,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Amelia_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  }
]
```

These are the users that have been added.

When the updateUserList endpoint is called it returns:

```
[
  {
    "staffID": 1,
    "dept": "Junior Web Developer",
    "email": "manasaN@tpionline.com",
    "name": "manasa",
    "password": "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3Rv.aJFJALiY0y1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 2,
    "dept": "Web Developer",
    "email": "juliof@tpionline.net",
    "name": "Julio Fajardo",
    "password": "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1ZERZDn9uvCqK1/1nd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 3,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "johnf@tpionline.com",
    "name": "John Fester",
    "password": "$2y$10$/oa/ESQmhhc5WvxrQKoUU.Pj5sM3gZY5FccilGfCUL5eyeOU5IDSa"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 5,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "fakeguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "Test",
    "password": "$2y$10$VWnnw5gRTN2absWos04fsOixW6TjOepNa3n0v/7ybFqsFZL8oPiJm"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 6,
    "dept": "Conf room",
    "email": "conf2@gmail.com",
    "name": "Conf 1st floor",
    "password": "$2y$10$KAZa1k2Sd/rg6dnVeqw4duB/XbAhcVXP.Fze6Zle3ZhcMaRphloG."
  },
  {
    "staffID": 8,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "newguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "New guy",
    "password": ""
  },
  {
    "staffID": 9,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "nguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "New Guy2",
    "password": ""
  },
  {
    "staffID": 12,
    "dept": "Test ADD",
    "email": "cristinab@tpionline.com",
    "name": "Cristina Bermudez",
    "password": "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001caJJmeReHnaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 30,
    "dept": "Erwing",
    "email": "erwingh@tpionline.com",
    "name": "Erwing Hernandez",
    "password": "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6BBaxn4B070pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"
  }
]
```

What I need to accomplish is that if the there is no current user whose ID equals the staff ID it should be set in the state so i can add this user. With the data above the users that should be added should be 
have the staff ID of: 5, 6, 12,30.

Right Now My functions returns:

```
0: {staffID: 8, dept: "Fake Title", email: "newguy@gmail.net", name: "New guy", password: ""}
1: {staffID: 9, dept: "Fake Title", email: "nguy@gmail.net", name: "New Guy2", password: ""}
2: {staffID: 12, dept: "Test ADD", email: "cristinab@tpionline.com", name: "Cristina Bermudez", password: "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001caJJmeReHnaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"}
3: {staffID: 30, dept: "Erwing", email: "erwingh@tpionline.com", name: "Erwing Hernandez", password: "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6BBaxn4B070pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let currentUserIds = currentUserBox.map(user => user.id)
let newUsers = newUserBox.filter(newUser => !currentUserIds.includes(newUser.staffID))
```

`newUsers` is the array you want.
The code would look something like this:

```js
let currentUserBox = [{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Elton",
    "lastName": "Frederick",
    "departmentId": 1,
    "admin": true,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Developer",
    "vh5given": 31,
    "vh5rec": 280,
    "profilePic": "https://www.travelplannersinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Elton.jpg",
    "password": "abc234"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Julio",
    "lastName": "Probando",
    "departmentId": 1,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": true,
    "position": "Lead Dev",
    "vh5given": 11,
    "vh5rec": 339,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Julio_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc232"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Corey",
    "lastName": "Chris",
    "departmentId": 2,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Customer Service",
    "vh5given": 14,
    "vh5rec": 167,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Corey.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "Daisy",
    "lastName": "Ramos",
    "departmentId": 3,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "ATC",
    "vh5given": 22,
    "vh5rec": 202,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Daisy_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc321"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "firstName": "Air Car Hotel",
    "lastName": "Nunca",
    "departmentId": 4,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 25,
    "profilePic": "profile.jpg",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "firstName": "Jenn",
    "lastName": "Lee",
    "departmentId": 4,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Vp Of Sales",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 0,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Jenn2_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "firstName": "Reyna",
    "lastName": "Pagan",
    "departmentId": 5,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Agent Support Manager",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 20,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Reyna_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "firstName": "Ameilia",
    "lastName": "Rodriguez",
    "departmentId": 6,
    "admin": false,
    "hasApproval": false,
    "position": "Human Resources",
    "vh5given": 0,
    "vh5rec": 5,
    "profilePic": "https://388616.smushcdn.com/941012/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Amelia_.jpg?lossy=1&strip=1&webp=1",
    "password": "abc123"


  }
]

let newUserBox = [{
    "staffID": 1,
    "dept": "Junior Web Developer",
    "email": "manasaN@tpionline.com",
    "name": "manasa",
    "password": "$2y$10$/zYS7OhzwdLOi6Slzc3Rv.aJFJALiY0y1J6MjnLCN24GmZ3rMHWUS"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 2,
    "dept": "Web Developer",
    "email": "juliof@tpionline.net",
    "name": "Julio Fajardo",
    "password": "$2y$10$MphAC8aRY2uzs1ZERZDn9uvCqK1/1nd7t0KukEkvGbx5Y4van.Da6"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 3,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "johnf@tpionline.com",
    "name": "John Fester",
    "password": "$2y$10$/oa/ESQmhhc5WvxrQKoUU.Pj5sM3gZY5FccilGfCUL5eyeOU5IDSa"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 5,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "fakeguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "Test",
    "password": "$2y$10$VWnnw5gRTN2absWos04fsOixW6TjOepNa3n0v/7ybFqsFZL8oPiJm"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 6,
    "dept": "Conf room",
    "email": "conf2@gmail.com",
    "name": "Conf 1st floor",
    "password": "$2y$10$KAZa1k2Sd/rg6dnVeqw4duB/XbAhcVXP.Fze6Zle3ZhcMaRphloG."
  },
  {
    "staffID": 8,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "newguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "New guy",
    "password": ""
  },
  {
    "staffID": 9,
    "dept": "Fake Title",
    "email": "nguy@gmail.net",
    "name": "New Guy2",
    "password": ""
  },
  {
    "staffID": 12,
    "dept": "Test ADD",
    "email": "cristinab@tpionline.com",
    "name": "Cristina Bermudez",
    "password": "$2y$10$92I6fSJY6OW001caJJmeReHnaeF5tdHBjWHBmoCvX1RnfhTspjpBa"
  },
  {
    "staffID": 30,
    "dept": "Erwing",
    "email": "erwingh@tpionline.com",
    "name": "Erwing Hernandez",
    "password": "$2y$10$RWgOBbUHojgmyk3behYhd.kzdFEiH.6BBaxn4B070pS5q5Gf3ZYEa"
  }
]


let currentUserIds = currentUserBox.map(user => user.id)
let newUsers = newUserBox.filter(newUser => !currentUserIds.includes(newUser.staffID))

console.log(newUsers)
```

Comment: When I try this i get "currentUserBox.map is not a function"

Comment: In your case array is stored in currentUserBox.data so replace newUserBox with newUserBox.data and currentUserBox with currentUserBox.data

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show you some example how to do it:

```js
const array1 = [{
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "One"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstName": "Three"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "firstName": "Five"
    }
];
const array2 = [{
        "staffID": 2,
        "firstName": "Staff Two"
    },
    {
        "staffID": 3,
        "firstName": "Staff Three"
    },
    {
        "staffID": 4,
        "firstName": "Staff Four"
    },

    {
        "staffID": 7,
        "firstName": "Staff Seven"
    }
];

const filtered = array1.filter(one => array2.filter(two => one.id !== two.staffID).length > 0);


console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Yours returns the staffId that equals the ID 3. I need it to return 2, 4, 7